# Is it possible for images to be displayed in Java program output?

Tags: java, output, photo

Say I have got a image file, which shows a dog (just for example). During execution, I want to display the image located at "C:\image.png" (again, just saying) to be displayed by using System.out.println or basic GUI by using Swing class. I am curious to know about it, so if it is possible, it'd be so helpful if you could kindly explain. Same for if not possible. Thanks a ton!

EDIT: **Is it impossible to include images in System.out.println**?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: "basic GUI by using Swing class" - it sounds like you already know of one solution here.

Comment: Oli, I am a beginner with GUI programming, so I do not know all aspects of advanced GUI, such as using the Graphics component and stuff. That's why I want an explanation if anything, if such is possible or not.

Comment: For GUI programming you have to learn Swings or you can learn Applets in java. 
Swings will help you to make awesome graphical user interface like buttons,pictures.
You are a beginner now,so first master the basics of java. Then you can proceed to GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for images of dogs as well as for images of cats.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ShowImage
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        showImage("C:/image.png");
    }

    private static void showImage(final String fileName)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
                f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(fileName)));
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For images of horses, slight adjustments might be necessary.

Comment: Hello Marco, thanks for your answer. Is it possible to output images via System.out.println?

Comment: @JavaGeek Are you talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art ? Otherwise: No, it's not possible...

Comment: So it's not working with SOPln, right? Thanks. Got to know about it. Maybe ASCII is better ;)